# Test Code Coverage is not getting displayed

Tags: unit-test, case-object

Based on the requirement ,we have created a vf page ,apex and test class written.When i run the test class ,the method gets passed but it shows 0 code coverage.
I shall appreciate your help.

VF Controller Code :

```
public with sharing class MassCaseClose {

      public Case objCase {get;set;} 
      private List<Case> lstCase; 
      public MassCaseClose() 
      { 
           objCase = new Case(); 
           lstCase = new List<Case>(); 
           String strRecordIds = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('ids');
            set<Id> setCaseIds = new set<Id>();
            for(String strid : strRecordIds.split(','))
            {
                setCaseIds.add(id.valueof(strid.trim()));
            }
            lstCase = [SELECT Id, Status FROM Case WHERE Id IN: setCaseIds];
     } 
     public PageReference save() 
   { 
      for(Case objCaseRecord: lstCase) 
    { 
      objCaseRecord.Status = objCase.Status; 
      objCaseRecord.Reason_For_Resolution__c = objCase.Reason_For_Resolution__c; 
      objCaseRecord.Closer_Comment__c=objCase.Closer_Comment__c;
      objCaseRecord.Do_Not_Send_Email_Case_Closure__c = objCase.Do_Not_Send_Email_Case_Closure__c; 
    } 
      update lstCase; 
      return new pagereference('/500'); 

   } 
     public PageReference cancel() 
    { 
      return new pagereference('/500'); 
  } 

}
```

Test Class :

```
@isTest
public class MassCaseCloseTest{
    public static TestMethod void TestMassCaseClose(){

       Account a = new Account();
        a.Name ='Testing Account';        
        insert a;

        Contact c = new Contact();
        c.FirstName ='Testing';
        c.LastName ='Contact';
        insert c;

        Case cas = new Case();
        cas.Status='Closed';
        cas.Reason_For_Resolution__c='Spam';
        cas.Closer_Comment__c='Testing for the Mass closer of Cases';
        insert cas;   

        Test.startTest();
        ApexPages.CurrentPage().getparameters().put('ids',cas.id);
        MassCaseClose objCase = new MassCaseClose ();
        /*objCase.Status = 'Closed';
        objCase.Closer_Comment__c='Testing for the Mass closer of Cases';*/
        objCase.save();
        Test.stopTest();
    }   
     public static TestMethod void TestMassCaseClose1(){

       Account a = new Account();
        a.Name ='Testing Account';        
        insert a;

        Contact c = new Contact();
        c.FirstName ='Testing ';
        c.LastName ='Contact';
        insert c;

        Case cas = new Case();
        cas.Status='Closed';
        cas.Reason_For_Resolution__c='Spam';
        cas.Closer_Comment__c='Testing for the Mass closer of Cases';
        insert cas;   

        Test.startTest();
        ApexPages.CurrentPage().getparameters().put('ids',cas.id);
        MassCaseClose objCase = new MassCaseClose ();
        /*objCase.Status = 'Closed';
        objCase.Closer_Comment__c='Testing for the Mass closer of Cases';*/
        objCase.Cancel();
        Test.stopTest();
    }   
   }
```

Comment: @Himanshu,@Poet:Thanks for your  reply....i still get errors....where one method gets executed and the other as fail...the code coverage is showing as 95%...it shows the line which didn't get covered as  "return new pagereference('/500');"

Comment: Could you update your question, possibly showing your updated test class. You have two `return new pagereference('/500');`. Which one isn't being covered?

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are not creating any instance of your class inside your test class

```
@isTest
public class MassCaseCloseTest{
public static TestMethod void TestMassCaseClose(){

   Account a = new Account();
    a.Name ='Testing EDB Account';        
    insert a;

    Contact c = new Contact();
    c.FirstName ='Testing EDB';
    c.LastName ='Contact';
    insert c;

    Case cas = new Case();
    cas.Status='Closed';
    cas.Reason_For_Resolution__c='Spam';
    cas.Closer_Comment__c='Testing for the Mass closer of Cases';
    insert cas;   

    Case cas1 = new Case();
    cas1.Status='Closed';
    cas1.Reason_For_Resolution__c='Spam1';
    cas1.Closer_Comment__c='Testing for the Mass closer of Case1s';
    insert cas1; 

    Test.startTest();
    ApexPages.CurrentPage().getparameters().put('ids',cas.id + ',' + cas1);
    /**********Class intance created so that we can call constructor and ave method
    MassCaseClose objCase = new MassCaseClose();
    objCase.save();
    Test.stopTest();
}   

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Himanshu's answer, I'd also point out I had a similar problem with this recently,

For me at least, when I was running a test in the Developer Console, tests were passing but they weren't showing any line coverage and displaying 0/# lines covered.

I fixed this by going to "Test" and ticking "Always Run Asynchronously".

[image]

I appreciate this answer might not be exactly what you're looking for, but it is something to look out for.